# Newbie - Authentication headers for Iphone webservices (ASP>net MVC 3.0 REST)

Tags: iphone, asp.net-mvc-3, restful-authentication

We are developing an Iphone app that will talk to the ASP.net MVC 3.0 webservcies with RESTful Urls. Almost all the action are available for authorized users only. I am not sure how this can be accomplished as we use membership provider at the webservice end. How do we pass the authentication parameters *(username and password) to MVC actions from iPhone app. I believe iPhone can send only parameters in query string and not as request headers.. Thanks for any quick response..

Comment: If you have found a solution to this question I would be interested in knowing the approach you used as I am trying to solve the same problem. I have tried to store the authentication cookie returned from ASP.NET Forms Authentication in NSHTTPCookieStore, then retrieve it and add it to the NSMutableURLRequest. However, so far I can not get the cookie storage to work.

Comment: Hi ChrisP, we are doing an alltogether differenbt approach now. We send the username and password as query string parameters over https, the response is an authentication token (guid) generated by the webservice. This authentication token is send along with all the other webservices to validate the request. Thus we avoid sending the secret thing s again and again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am far from an expert myself, but when you talk about the request headers don't you mean this?

```
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:MyURLString]];
[urlRequest setValue:@"aValue" forHTTPHeaderField:@"field"];
```

You can pass any parameter you want there.

Comment: Does the values we set here passed as query string? Is that a potential threat if i am sending params like username and password.. ?

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET authentication is cookie based by default so you would have to store the cookie on the device and send it with every request

Comment: ...which is done automatically by NSCookieStorage/NSURLConnection without developer intervention.